# Tkinter Canvas - I have some problems deleting a shape after its y2 dimension passes the screen to prevent lag

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tk-toolkit, tkinter-layout

I am creating a raining effects feature, and I have lag problems whenever I try to delete a shape thats y2 dimension passes the y axis of the screen. I have trouble making this work. My code is shown below.

```
from tkinter import  *
import random
import time
window = Tk()
window.title('Raining Effects')
HEIGHT = 600
WIDTH = 1000
c = Canvas(window, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH, bg='yellow')
c.pack()
x2 = 
for q in range(6):
    c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='white', 
dif = 0
var = c.create_text(500, 580, text='Rain Count:', fill='blue', font='Consolas 20 bold')
def rain_part(event):
    global dif
    global lists
    dif += 1
    lists = []
    for i in range(1, 50, 1):
        x1 = random.randint(WIDTH / 100, WIDTH - 10)
        global y1
        y1 = random.randint(1, 20)
        global a
        a = c.create_line(x1, y1, x1 + 10, y1 + 10, fill='lightblue', width=3)
        lists.append(a)
        c.itemconfig(var, text='Rain Count:' + str(lists[-1] + dif - 1))

def del_part():
    # I have a problem creating the 'y2 dimension of shape passing y axis' condition
    c.delete(a)
def move_part(event):
    c.move('all', 0, 20)
    c.move(var, 0, -20)        
 


c.bind_all('<KeyPress-space>', rain_part)
c.bind_all('<Down>', move_part)
```

Comment: Note that my code is unfinished.

Comment: post a [minimal runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)